# R: check mandatory/required arguments are provided

Tags: r, arguments

I'd like to be able to have a way to check all arguments without defaults are specified when calling a function in R. This seems like a sensible thing to do to me, as it avoids a function failing later on (which could be after a lot of processing) when a value is found to be missing.

One way to accomplish this task would be to write a `if (missing(arg))` statement for each argument, but this requires keeping the arguments for the function and the above statements consistent with each other, so I'm looking for a better solution.

At present I use the following function, which works in most cases, but not all.

```
# check for required arguments by getting arguments for the
# definition of the calling function and comparing to the arguments 
# in the function call
check_required_args <- function () {
    def    <- sys.function(-1)
    f_args <- formals(def)
    f_args <- f_args[sapply(f_args, is.name)]  # remove arguments with defaults
    f_args <- names(f_args)
    f_args <- f_args[f_args != '...'] # remove ellipsis argument if present

    call   <- match.call(definition=def, call=sys.call(-1))
    f_name <- call[1]
    c_args <- names(as.list(call[-1]))

    for(n in f_args) {
        if (!n %in% c_args) {
            stop("Argument '", n, "' missing from call to function ", 
                f_name, "()", call.=FALSE)
        }
    }
}

f <- function(a, b, c=2) check_required_args()
f(a=1) # should fail (missing argument b)
f(2, 3) # should work
f(2, c=5) # should fail (missing argument b)
f(2, 3, 4) # should work


f <- function(a, b, ...) f2(a, b, ...)
f2 <- function(a, b, c, ...) check_required_args()

f2(a=1, b=2, c=3) # should work
f2(a=1, b=2) # should fail (missing argument c for function f2)
f(a=1, b=2, c=3) # should work
f(a=1, b=2) # should fail  (missing argument c for function f2)
```

Can this function be improved to work in all of these cases? If not is there a more appropriate solution to perform this check?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to do this?  One of the great things about `R` 's lazy evaluation is that unneeded arguments can be ignored.  Not to mention that the reason you put arguments into the formals of a function in the first place is to use them!  So, the proper answer to your question is: no, it is **not** a "sensible" thing to do.

Comment: I've had several functions where an argument is not used until later in the function, at which point the function will throw an error due to the missing argument. When the function takes hours to run, this is seriously annoying, so for some situations I want to check if all required arguments are specified before evaluating any further. Seems reasonable to me?

Comment: No, it seems that you're making fundamental programming mistakes. First, don't put so much processing into a single function that it takes that long to run: write multiple functions and script them together. "Good" functions IMHO should not require a huge number of input parameters; you may want to consider building your (validated) dataset into a `list` variable.   Second, at some point you've gotta do input validation not only for existence but for proper data type (e.g. character vs. numeric).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this?

```
check_required_args <- function (fun = sys.function(-1), ncall = 3) {
  f_args <- formals(fun)
  f_args <- f_args[vapply(f_args, is.symbol, FUN.VALUE = TRUE)]
  f_args <- names(f_args)
  f_args <- setdiff(f_args, "...")
  test <- vapply(f_args, 
                 function(x) missingArg(as.name(x), envir = parent.frame(ncall), eval = TRUE), 
                 FUN.VALUE = TRUE)
  stopifnot(!any(test))
  return(invisible(NULL))     
}


f <- function(a, b, c=2) {
  check_required_args()
  return("Hello!")
}
f(a=1) # should fail (missing argument b)
#Error: !any(test) is not TRUE

f(2, 3) # should work
#[1] "Hello!"

f(2, c=5) # should fail (missing argument b)
# Error: !any(test) is not TRUE

f(2, 3, 4) # should work
#[1] "Hello!"

x <- 1
f(a=x, 3)
#[1] "Hello!"


f <- function(a, b, ...) f2(a, b, ...)
f2 <- function(a, b, c, ...) {
  check_required_args()
  return("Hello!")
}

f2(a=1, b=2, c=3) # should work
#[1] "Hello!"

f2(a=1, b=2) # should fail (missing argument c for function f2)
#Error: !any(test) is not TRUE 

f(a=1, b=2, c=3) # should work
#[1] "Hello!"

f(a=1, b=2) # should fail  (missing argument c for function f2)
#Error: !any(test) is not TRUE
```

### Edit:

You might want to use `get` to check for existence:

```
check_required_args <- function (fun = sys.function(-1), ncall = 3) {
  f_args <- formals(fun)
  f_args <- f_args[vapply(f_args, is.symbol, FUN.VALUE=TRUE)]
  f_args <- names(f_args)
  f_args <- setdiff(f_args, "...")
  test <- lapply(f_args, 
                 function(x) {
                   get(x, envir = parent.frame(ncall), inherits = TRUE)
                   return(NULL)
                   })
  #possibly use a for loop instead
  #wrap in tryCatch for customized error messages

}

f <- function(a, b, ...) f2(a, b, ...)
f2 <- function(a, b, c, ...) {
  check_required_args()
  return("Hello!")
}

f(c=2)
#Error in get(x, envir = parent.frame(ncall), inherits = TRUE) : 
#  argument "a" is missing, with no default
```

If you don't want check in enclosing frames, set `inherits = FALSE`.

Comment: Thanks. I would think `f(c=2)` should also fail, but it passes the tests here?

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix that to your expectations. `a` and `b` are not missing in `f2`, but only in `f`. Thus, a check in `f2` can't tell you that they are missing in `f`. Do I understand you correctly that you wish to follow the call stack and check for all enclosing functions? It might be easier to force evaluation of arguments at the beginning of `f2`.

Comment: Just be aware that this might create performance problems (in particular if parameters can be big objects).